# Отобразить весь xml файл при нажатие на строку таблицы JS

Tags: javascript, xml

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать открытие на страничке двух xml-файлов(просто показать содержимое, как оно есть),которые появляются при нажатии на строку.

Здесь отображается первый xml файл

```
    <div class="jumbotron mt-3" style="text-align: center;">
        <h1 id="headerTitle">xml-запрос</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="app"></div>

</div>
```

Здесь отображается второй xml файл

```
    <div class="container">

    <div class="jumbotron mt-3" style="text-align: center;">
        <h1 id="headerTitle">xml-ответ</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="app"></div>

</div>
```

Вот сама таблица в которой хранятся пути к xml файлам

```
            <table class="table align-items-center table-flush" id="example">
                <thead class="thead-light">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">первый файл</th>
                        <th scope="col">второй файл</th>
                     </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></th>
                        <td><?php echo $row['first']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['second']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function(){
    $('#t_trud').on('click', '.rowlink',function(){
    var x = $(this).find('#firstFile').html();
    var y = $(this).find('#secondFile').html(); 
    $("#firstBlock").html(`<iframe type="application/xml" src="${x}" height="300px" width="500px" scrolling="auto"></iframe>`);
    $("#secondBlock").html(`<iframe type="application/xml" src="${y}" height="300px" width="500px" scrolling="auto"></iframe>`);
    });
    });
```